# Definition of image of a subset

Tags: functions

Is it a correct way to define image of a subset?
$$
f : A \to B\ \text{ function} \\ S\subseteq A \\
f(S)= \left\{b ∈ B ∣ S\cap f^{-1}(\left\{b\right\})≠∅\right\}
$$

Comment: It looks sound to me

Comment: It's mathematically correct, but what's wrong with $f(S) = \{ f(a) \mid a\in S\}$?

Comment: I would say that Greg Martin has given the *correct* definition of the image of $f$, and your expression is an easily proved theorem about it. But that is a personal preference, not some requirement.